# Are there some good and tension free custom fonts available to use with sIFR, @font-face etc?

Tags: css, xhtml, fonts, sifr, font-face

Is there any free font available to use with sIFR @font-face etc?

if i use those then nobody will file a court case on me, no body will send any legal notice to me.?

Are thee good tension free, license free fonts available to use personally, commercially in my projects, in client projects?

Nobody should send any notice to my lovely clients about font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

Comment: are all font are tension free  on this site?

Comment: Can we download and use fontsquirrel's fonts with  sIFR?

Comment: “100% free for commercial use” is pretty unequivocal! I'm not sure what you mean by “tension”. Click through ‘Font Info’ to find download links to the plain TTF/OTF versions.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fontspace.com/ is a good resource. Visiting the page for the font shows the fonts licencing info, but its probably good practice to visit the font authors website and look for the copyright licencing info. Sometimes licencing info will be contained within the downloaded font file in a text document. Fonts that are freeware and have a 'commecial use allowed' licence is what you're looking for.